# Unstable results using LSTM for High Frequency stock forecasting

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, stock

I have several datasets containing High Frequency data (Limit Order Books) from Nasdaq.

For whoever is interested in this kind of data, I strongly suggest checking out https://github.com/martinobdl/ITCH for a Book Constructor and some sample data (more than you gonna get anywhere else, anyway)

I would like to use an LSTM network to try and predict both the next bid and next ask price, using some other features as well, such as volumes and volumes imbalances from the order book.

This is how the first five columns of my train data look like (data from AAPL, 1s between datapoints):

```
Bid     Ask        1_bid_vol  1_ask_vol  2_bid_vol  2_ask_vol   
162.49  162.52     300.0      200.0      500.0      200.0       
162.48  162.51     300.0      600.0      800.0      500.0       
162.49  162.51     100.0      10.0       1000.0     500.0       
162.48  162.52     469.0      600.0      618.0      500.0
```

As well as normalizing data, I create fixed-lenght sequences, as it's appropriate for LSTMs, as follows:

```
def slicing(df,history_size):
data = []
labels = []
tmp_df=np.array(df)
start_index = history_size
for i in range(start_index, len(df)):
    indices = range(i-history_size, i)
    data.append(tmp_df[indices,:])
    labels.append(tmp_df[i,:2])

return np.array(data), np.array(labels)
```

So that input data have shape = (n_samples, history_size, n_features)

My current architecture is as follows:

```
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)
LSTM = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128,input_shape= 
      (X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2]),activation='relu',return_sequences=True),
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(62,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2]),activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
   ])
 opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
 LSTM.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse')
 LSTM.fit(x=X_train,y=y_train, epochs=50, validation_data=(X_val,y_val),callbacks=[callback])
```

These are the results I get on the validation set using 14k datapoints for training (I'll let y'all imagine what it's like on the test set):

[Predictions on validation set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6JIu.png)

As you can see, the model starts off well on the validation set, than it basically starts predicting random outliers/spikes along the way.

Note that this result consistently appears even after changing hyperparameters, model architecture, and even changing data (e.g. using other stocks), and using smaller timewindows so that I can use way more data to train. Given this, I suspect it must be some kind of common problem, and any help/resource from someone who experienced it / is well versed in using RNN/LSTMs would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your expectation that the model will be able to forecast the stock value 2000 time units ahead?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a LSTM model to predict future stock prices, but it predicts the next day's stock price, not the next second's stock price. I made millions and millions of dollars using this strategy, and other very similar strategies, but it take a little time to make millions and I don't think you're going to do it in one second.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

start = '2019-06-30'
end = '2020-06-30'

tickers = ['GOOG']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Open','Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Open', 'Adj Close']])

#names = np.reshape(price_data, (len(price_data), 1))

df = pd.concat(price_data)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

for col in df.columns: 
    print(col) 
    
#used for setting the output figure size
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20,10
#to normalize the given input data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
#to read input data set (place the file name inside  ' ') as shown below


df['Adj Close'].plot()
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.show()

ntrain = 80
df_train = df.head(int(len(df)*(ntrain/100)))
ntest = -80
df_test = df.tail(int(len(df)*(ntest/100)))


#importing the packages 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM

#dataframe creation
seriesdata = df.sort_index(ascending=True, axis=0)
new_seriesdata = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(df)),columns=['Date','Adj Close'])
length_of_data=len(seriesdata)
for i in range(0,length_of_data):
    new_seriesdata['Date'][i] = seriesdata['Date'][i]
    new_seriesdata['Adj Close'][i] = seriesdata['Adj Close'][i]
#setting the index again
new_seriesdata.index = new_seriesdata.Date
new_seriesdata.drop('Date', axis=1, inplace=True)
#creating train and test sets this comprises the entire data’s present in the dataset
myseriesdataset = new_seriesdata.values
totrain = myseriesdataset[0:255,:]
tovalid = myseriesdataset[255:,:]
#converting dataset into x_train and y_train
scalerdata = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scale_data = scalerdata.fit_transform(myseriesdataset)
x_totrain, y_totrain = [], []
length_of_totrain=len(totrain)
for i in range(60,length_of_totrain):
    x_totrain.append(scale_data[i-60:i,0])
    y_totrain.append(scale_data[i,0])
x_totrain, y_totrain = np.array(x_totrain), np.array(y_totrain)
x_totrain = np.reshape(x_totrain, (x_totrain.shape[0],x_totrain.shape[1],1))

In [85]:

#LSTM neural network
lstm_model = Sequential()
lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_totrain.shape[1],1)))
lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=50))
lstm_model.add(Dense(1))
lstm_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adadelta')
lstm_model.fit(x_totrain, y_totrain, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
#predicting next data stock price
myinputs = new_seriesdata[len(new_seriesdata) - (len(tovalid)+1) - 60:].values
myinputs = myinputs.reshape(-1,1)
myinputs  = scalerdata.transform(myinputs)
tostore_test_result = []
for i in range(60,myinputs.shape[0]):
    tostore_test_result.append(myinputs[i-60:i,0])
tostore_test_result = np.array(tostore_test_result)
tostore_test_result = np.reshape(tostore_test_result,(tostore_test_result.shape[0],tostore_test_result.shape[1],1))
myclosing_priceresult = lstm_model.predict(tostore_test_result)
myclosing_priceresult = scalerdata.inverse_transform(myclosing_priceresult)
    
totrain = df_train
tovalid = df_test

#predicting next data stock price
myinputs = new_seriesdata[len(new_seriesdata) - (len(tovalid)+1) - 60:].values


#  Printing the next day’s predicted stock price. 
print(len(tostore_test_result));
print(myclosing_priceresult);
```

Result:

```
[[1396.532]]
```

You can find a few other samples of predicting future stock prices at my blog, below.

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks

Comment: Yea sure thing you did man, I don't see how that helps me tho